# Links/hover effect not working on certain part of page in fixed navigation bar

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navigation, nav

I've been working on a simple website for a friend and decided to use Weebly (yes I know, nooby) since I didn't want to start from scratch for a simple website. I've added a fixed navigation bar on the right side of the page in form of circular buttons with links attached to them. Unfortunately, as I'm scrolling, the links and hover effects stop working (buttons still scroll properly) once I reach a text box on the page. As soon as it passes it, they work again. Since I'm using Weebly I can't fully access all of the html in the page but I have full access to the CSS files. This is what my code looks like for the nav bar with 3 buttons:

```
<div data-spy="affix" class="offset8 span1 well offset7 small  nav">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <p><a href="#A"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wV1JVH2.png" height="32" width="32" onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/whPzX4a.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/wV1JVH2.png'" <a></p>
<p><a href="#B"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wV1JVH2.png" height="32" width="32" onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/whPzX4a.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/wV1JVH2.png'" <a></p>
<p><a href="#L384"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wV1JVH2.png" height="32" width="32" onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/whPzX4a.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/wV1JVH2.png'" <a></p>
        </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
nav {
position: fixed;
float: right;
right: 0px;
!important;
}
```

And here's a couple images of it in action, showing the issue:

[image: Working before the textbox]

[image: Not working during the textbox]

Again, I unfortunately can't access the code for the textbox because it's in Weebly.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css is wrong. It should be something like this:

```
ul.nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    right: 0px;
    top: 20%; /* Change this to your needs */
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Appreciate the help my friend!

Comment: Great :) glad that it worked. Can you also approve the answer? :)